# How to rotate image in the speedometer?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I am using this code for rotate animation:

```
CABasicAnimation *spinAnimation = [CABasicAnimation
                                   animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
spinAnimation.fromValue =[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
spinAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.30];
spinAnimation.duration =2;  
[imgArrow.layer addAnimation:spinAnimation forKey:@"spinAnimation"];
```

In this code imageview's bottom point is not fixed. I want to set up the image such that it rotates from a fixed point on the bottom of the image (like a speedometer).

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"arrow" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
CGImageRef image = img.CGImage;
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 365.0, 305);
CGContextRotateCTM(context, angle); 
touchRect = CGRectMake(-10.0, -5.0, img.size.width, img.size.height); // (-10.0, -5.0) - arrow's rotation center
CGContextDrawImage(context, touchRect, image);  

CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Comment: touchRect is undeclared . How do I declare it ?

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty old now, but the answer has to do with the anchor point. You just need to set the anchor point for the image view to be the bottom center. Here's a guide to show the different anchor points.
[image]

So you would set your layer's anchor point at 0.5, 1.0 like this:

```
[[imgArrow layer] setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)];
```

Answer (score 0):

To rotate arrow from anchor point use this code:

```
 self.button.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(self.button.layer.anchorPoint.x, self.button.layer.anchorPoint.y*2);

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
[self.button setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((M_PI / 180) * -40.0579987)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```